# recursively sort an array in ascending order using a swap, and finding smallest function

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, recursion

i need to recursively sort an array in ascending order, while finding the smallest index and swapping it for the first place in the array etc. i wrote a code but not sure where it is going wrong. i have two functions one that just simply swaps between two index's, and one to find the smallest number in the array and return the index of it.

```
void Swap(int a[], int i, int j) 
{
    int temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
}

int smallest(int *arr, int size)
{
    int small;
    if (size == 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    small = smallest(arr, size - 1);//go from the last to the first index in the array and then work backwards to find the smallest one all the way back to the beginning
    return (arr[size - 1] < arr[small]) ? size - 1 : small;
}

void chooseSort(int * arr, int size, int left)
{
    if (left == size -1)
    {
        return;
    }
    int index = smallest(arr, size);
    Swap(arr, index, left);
    chooseSort(arr, size, left + 1);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right place to debug your code. That said, when you recursively call chooseSort, don't you always find the same smallest element since you always look for the smallest element in the same range ? Maybe you should call chooseSort(arr+1,size-1, left) instead ? Something like this https://ideone.com/R0yXOG (btw, a for loop would be clearer than your "smallest" function)

Comment: I guess `int index = smallest(arr + left, size - left);` would already be better, but with `chooseSort(arr+1,size-1)` you don't need `left` since it's always 0.